# Using a variable to type cast in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, function, generics, casting

I have two functions that are nearly identical and I want to merge them into one but I cannot find out how to handle the type casting in my if-let statement.  There are only two solutions that I can think of but I cannot execute either of them.

Here are the two functions (there's a lot more to them but this is the only part that is causing me trouble in the merge):

```
    func loadNextEventViewController() {
        if let nextEventViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EventViewController") as? EventViewController {

            // Executed code in here

        }
    }

    func loadFinishViewController() {
        if let finishViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FinishViewController") as? FinishViewController {

            // Executed code in here

        }
    }
```

My first attempt was to make a generic parameter that could accept either the EventViewController OR FinalViewController, but as far as I can tell, there is no logical OR for generic parameters, only logical AND.

My second attempt was to create a computer variable but this didn't work either.

How can I take an argument in my function call that I could cast to be either class type in my if-let block?

Example:
`func loadViewController(identifier: String, viewControllerType: UIViewController)`

I've solved this issue in a very clunky way by using an in-else statement but I'd like to find a more elegant way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
func load(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
    if viewController is EventViewController {
        //do stuff
    }

    if viewController is FinishViewController {
        //do stuff
    }

    //do stuff that applies to all types of view controllers
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
    let eventVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EventViewController")
    load(eventVC)
```

If you want to avoid using if statements you can use a switch statement instead, like so:

```
func load(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
    switch viewController {
    case is EventViewController:
          //do stuff for EventViewController
    case is FinishViewController:
          //do stuff for FinishViewControllers
    default:
          //do stuff for other types, or break
    }
    //do stuff that applies to all viewControllers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of casting.. in your application you have two options, move to one vc or the other. There could be alot of logic that makes this decision or not. but either way, a decision HAS to be made at some point on what VC to show. You just need to decide on the best place to make this decision.

based on what you've shown so far, you could just do:

```
func showController(identifier: String) {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as? UIViewController {
            // Executed code in here
        }
}
```

I presume though, that each route has a different actions that require handling differently. The most common approach here is to use a segue, then you can use prepareForSegue to capture the segue and set properties as required based on the segue identifier. If you can provide some more information I can provide a better answer.

The main thing you need to consider here are.. whats actually different between the two. determine this and you can refactor your code to reduce repetition

Comment: Thanks! I'm constantly trying to refactor my code and find elegant solutions to become a better programmer but I guess the if-else statement was inevitable.

Comment: yeah, thats why i emphasized the decision has to be made somewhere :) good luck with the project

Comment: Thanks :) I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
 func loadViewController(identifier: String) {
      let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as? ViewController
      if let eventVC = vc as? EventViewController {
          // Executed code in here
      } else if let finishVC = vc as? FinishViewController {
          // Executed code in here
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you!  This solution is pretty close to what I came up with (not to imply that your solution is clunky)